# Javascript for loop sums

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to find the sums of a set of numbers from a for loop

I currently have

```
var num = "";
for(var i = 1; i < 11; i +=1){
    num = num + i;
}
console.log(num)
```

which gives me     `12345678910` in the JS console

I want to produce `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=SUM`

I have tried adding a "+" string:
    `num = num + i + "+";` 
    but it gives me `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+`

My question is how to add the "+" and "=" into the code and get the sum.

Comment: You are concatenating instead of adding.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to JS so my question might be hard to understand

Comment: You explicitly made the variable a string when you declared it with "".

Answer (score 1):

If you want the + to display AND the actual sum, then do this

```
var realSum = 0;
var num = "1";
for(var i = 2; i < 11; i +=1){
    realSum = realSum + i;
    num = num + "+" + i;
}
num = num + "=" + realSum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/kx9b7qu7/2

Using Eval

```
    var num = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < 11; i +=1){
        num.push(i)
    }
    var equation = num.join('+');
    var sum = eval(equation);

    console.log('Method 1: ',equation + '=' + sum)
```

Without using Eval

```
    var num = [];
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 1; i < 11; i +=1){
        num.push(i)
        sum += i    
    }
    var equation = num.join('+');

    console.log('Method 2: ',equation + '=' + sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an util out of it for later use ;) There are also other ways that make use of functional approach (reduce, map) and things that aren't widely supported yet (generators, array comprehensions).

Here are some example functions for consideration and tweaking:

---

```
// kind of usual

var sumRange = function (from, to, step) {

  var i,
      sum = from,
      str = from;

  for (i = from + step; i <= to; i += step) {
    sum += i;
    str += '+' + i;
  };

  str += '=' + sum;

  return str;

};

// sum of elements in arithmetic progression

var sumRangeAP = function (from, to, step) {

  var i,
      n,
      str = from;

  n = ((to - from) / step) + 1;

  for (i = from + step; i <= to; i += step) {
    str += '+' + i;
  };

  str += '=' + ((from + to) / 2) * n;

  return str;

};

// memory efficiency (not creating hell a lot of strings) together with some functional stuff
// on the other hand it looks like assignment operators (+,  +=) win with .join in terms of speed sometimes
// in many cases, I think, you may not give a shit about whether you use this or that

var sumRangeME = function (from, to, step) {

  var i,
      sum = from,
      str = [from];

  for (i = from + step; i <= to; i += step) {
    str.push(i);
  };

  return str.join('+') + '=' + str.reduce(function (prevVal, curVal) { return prevVal + curVal; });

};

console.log(sumRange(0,20,1));
console.log(sumRangeAP(0,20,1));
console.log(sumRangeME(0,20,1));
console.log(sumRange(1,21,1));
console.log(sumRangeAP(1,21,1));
console.log(sumRangeME(1,21,1));
console.log(sumRange(7,36,1));
console.log(sumRangeAP(7,36,1));
console.log(sumRangeME(7,36,1));
```

---

Answer (score -1):

In javascript + can also concatenate a string, if that's what seems best - it thinks you are putting two strings together so it concatenates them. Make num start as 0 instead, that should fix it.

Comment: Oh I see, well, my apologies

Comment: I don't really see the need for an apology, the question is just unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `var num=""` try with `var num=0`, because this way the operator `+` is used as string concatenation. `num=0` will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I thought you wanted to see the "math" equation try the following:

```
var numbers = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < 11; i += 1){
    numbers += i;
}

console.log(numbers);
```

Try this:

```
var numbers = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 11; i += 1){
    numbers.push(i);
}

var string = numbers.join("+");

string += "=" + eval(numbers.join("+"));

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're really trying to concatenate then

```
num = num + "+" + i;
```